# Предупреждение Google Play Console - Эти API в сером списке

Tags: android, android-sdk, google-play-console

Загрузил приложение в Google Play Console. После тестирования появляется предупреждение:

> Эти API в сером списке. Google не гарантирует, что они будут работать на существующих версиях Android. Возможно, использование некоторых из них уже не поддерживается целевым пакетом разработчика.

Есть трассировка стека:

```
StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.NonSdkApiUsedViolation: Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z
at android.os.StrictMode.lambda$static$1(StrictMode.java:428)
at android.os.-$$Lambda$StrictMode$lu9ekkHJ2HMz0jd3F8K8MnhenxQ.accept(Unknown Source:2)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethodInternal(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2064)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2047)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.ViewUtils.<clinit>(ViewUtils.java:44)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.ViewUtils.makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows(Unknown Source:0)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:827)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:659)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:552)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
at alexandr.SingleFragmentActivity12.onCreate(SingleFragmentActivity12.java:19)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7144)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7135)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
at androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:184)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2931)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3086)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1816)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

и трассировка второго вхождения:

```
StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.NonSdkApiUsedViolation: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V
at android.os.StrictMode.lambda$static$1(StrictMode.java:428)
at android.os.-$$Lambda$StrictMode$lu9ekkHJ2HMz0jd3F8K8MnhenxQ.accept(Unknown Source:2)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethodInternal(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.getPublicMethodRecursive(Class.java:2075)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2063)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1690)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.ViewUtils.makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows(ViewUtils.java:84)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:827)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:659)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:552)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
at alexandr.SingleFragmentActivity12.onCreate(SingleFragmentActivity12.java:19)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7144)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7135)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
at androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:184)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2931)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3086)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1816)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Судя из стека, интерфейсы из серого списка API использует класс "SingleFragmentActivity12", ниже код оттуда:

```
import android.os.Bundle;    
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;    
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;   




public abstract class SingleFragmentActivity12 extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected abstract Fragment createFragment();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment12);
        FragmentManager fm=getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment=fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container12);
        if(fragment==null){
            fragment=createFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container12,fragment)
                    .commit();

        }
    }
}
```

Что нужно сделать, чтобы API были из белого списка и исчезло предупреждение Google Play Console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по этим ссылкам: [раз](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56608951/what-are-these-warnings-in-the-pre-launch-report-in-google-play), [два](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51988819/android-p-api-28-what-does-the-strictmode-policy-violation-smartselectionev) у вас в разметке фрагмента/активити есть какие-то вьюхи, которые используют метод `androidx.appcompat.widget.ViewUtils.makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows`, который, в свою очередь, видимо, использует аналогично названный метод класса View, упомянутый в [списке методов](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/pie-release/config/hiddenapi-light-greylist.txt) (строка 6425), которые однажды прекратят работать.

Т.к., видимо, методы эти у вас вызываются гугловыми либами, то вам ничего делать не надо кроме своевременного обновления библиотек гугла. А она у вас и так, видимо, из свежих.

---

Возможно стоит попробовать удалять поочерёдно элементы разметки и смотреть, не исчезнет ли предупреждение - так будет понятно в чём именно причина.

Вроде бы вот этот код должен вам выдавать что-то похожее на предупреждение из консоли:

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
    StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
            .detectNonSdkApiUsage()
            .penaltyLog()
            .build());
}
```

Comment: Куда нужно добавить этот код?

Comment: @AlexB, по идее в любое место в приложении. Хоть бы и в самое начало `onCreate` метод `MainActivity`. Вроде бы оно должно вам что-то в логи вывести.

Comment: Спасибо @ЮрийСПб♦. Добавление Вашего кода вывело сообщение в логах, что методов соответствующих detectNonSdkApiUsage() не найдено.Думаю, это будет устранено с обновлением библиотек, попробую проверить путем удаления элементов разметки, если что отпишусь.

Answer (score 0):

Видимо библиотеки были обновлены, предупреждение исчезло само собой.